# SQL: determine that an activity occurs with a given frequency

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

A common problem in electronic-medical-record (EMR) reporting in determining that an activity occurs with a specific frequency.  In this situation, I need to determine that a note was written every 72-hours after admission.

Given:

```
A                                       D
|-0-|-1-|-2-|-3-|-4-|-5-|-6-|-7-|-8-|-9-|
|---- 1 ----|---- 2 ----|---- 3 ----|-4-|
```

There would need to be at least one note during periods 1, 2, and 3.  Because 4 isn't a full 72-hour period, it doesn't require a note.  Failure to find a note in periods 1, 2, and 3 would be a FAIL.

Data:

(ENC):

```
ENC_ID  ADMITTED    DISCHARGED  PERIODS PASS_FAIL
4114221 06/15/09 18:30  06/24/09 15:40  3   ?
```

PERIODS:    `TRUNC(CEIL((DISCHARGED - ADMITTED)/3))`

The 'PASS_FAIL' column would indicate if the encounter had an adequate number and timing of notes.

(NOTE):

```
ENC_ID  NOTE_ID NOTE_TIME   PERIOD
4114221 1833764 06/17/09 08:42  1
4114221 1843613 06/18/09 08:14  1
4114221 1858159 06/18/09 20:15  2
4114221 1850948 06/18/09 20:15  2
4114221 1850912 06/18/09 20:18  2
4114221 1859315 06/19/09 18:35  2
4114221 1863982 06/20/09 10:29  2
4114221 1868895 06/21/09 22:00  3
4114221 1873539 06/22/09 15:42  3
```

PERIOD: `CEIL((NOTE_TIME - ADMITTED)/3)`

Is there an efficient way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  e.*,
        CASE WHEN cnt = TRUNC(CEIL((discharged / admitted) / 3)) THEN 'pass' ELSE 'fail' END AS pass_fail
FROM    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM    enc ei
        CROSS JOIN
                (
                SELECT  level AS period
                FROM    dual
                CONNECT BY
                        level <= 
                        (
                        SELECT  TRUNC(CEIL((discharged / admitted) / 3))
                        FROM    enc
                        WHERE   enc_id = :enc_id
                        )
                ) p
        WHERE   ei.enc_id = :enc_id
                AND EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  NULL
                FROM    note
                WHERE   enc_id = ei.enc_id
                        AND note_time >= ei.admitted + (p - 1) * 3
                        AND note_time < ei.admitted + p * 3
                )
        ) c
JOIN    enc e
ON      e.enc_id = :enc_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly `NOTE` is a table with the data indicated.

All you really care about is whether the periods 1, 2 & 3 exist in the notes table for each `enc_id`.

If this is the case it indicates that an analytic function should be used:

```
select e.enc_id, e.admitted, e.discharged, e.periods
     , decode( n.ct
             , 'pass'
             , 'fail' ) as pass_fail
  from enc e
  left outer join ( select distinct enc_id
                         , count(n.period) over ( partition by n.enc_id ) as ct
                      from note
                     where period in (1,2,3)
                           ) n
    on e.enc_id = n.enc_id
```

This selects all period's per `enc_id` from `note`, which are the ones you want to examine. Then counts them per `enc_id`. The distinct is there to ensure you only get one row per `enc_id` in the final result.

If you only want those `enc_id`s that have a value in `note` then turn the left outer join into an inner join.

If `period` is not, as indicated, in the `note` query, you have to do a distinct on the full query rather than the sub-query and check which `period` each `note_id` is in.

I'm sorry about the horrible formatting but I wanted to try to fit it on the page.

```
select distinct e.enc_id, e.admitted, e.discharged, e.periods
     , decode( count( distinct -- number of distinct periods
                       case when n.note_time between e.admitted 
                                                 and e.admitted + 3 then 1
                            when n.note_time between e.admitted 
                                                 and e.admitted + 6 then 2
                            when n.note_time between e.admitted 
                                                 and e.admitted + 9 then 3
                            end ) -- per enc_id from note
                      over ( partition by n.enc_id )
              -- if it-s 3 then pass
             , 3, 'pass'
              -- else fail.
             , 'fail' ) as pass_fail
  from enc e
  left outer join note n
    on e.enc_id = n.enc_id
```

Whatever your data-structure the benefits of both ways are that they are simple joins, one index unique scan ( I'm assuming `enc.end_id` is unique ) and one index range scan ( on `note` ).

Comment: NOTE is a group of tables; the PERIOD column is a calculation that makes it easier to determine which period the note 'satisfies' (so to speak).  The number of PERIODS is entirely dependent upon the ENC's ADMITTED and DISCHARED dates (minimum of 1, of course); I've seen ENCs with 10 PERIODS.  Said another way, the solution needs to adapt to the duration (i.e. the # PERIODS) of the ENC.